# Exercise on Divide&Conquer's technique

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, divide-and-conquer

I need help on this exercise:
You are given an array of n elements, and you notice that some of the elements are duplicates; that is, they appear more than once in the array. Show how to remove all duplicates from the array in time O(n log n).

I find a solution but in O(n^2)... How can I apply D&C?

Comment: And memorize initial positions in order to sort again, if you want to keep the initial order.

Comment: (You can do a merged merge sort dropping duplicates, D&C style.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an array of elements $a[i], 0\le i\le n-1$, we know we can sort it in time $O(n\log n)$. Then do the following to produce an array $b[\;]$:

```
declare b to be of size n
old = a[0]
b[0] = a[0]
j = 1
for i = 1, ... , n
   if a[i] =/= old    // found a new value
      old = a[i]      // save it
      b[j] = a[i]     // store it in b[j]
      j = j + 1       // and increment the b index
```

It's clear that, first, this can be done in one pass through the $a$ array, so this part will take time $O(n)$ (along with $O(n)$ time to allocate $b$), and, second, after this part the $b$ array will contain all of the values of the original array, with no duplicate values.

**Note**. This may or may not be what you want. Starting with an initial array $\langle\,7, 3, 7, 4, 1, 3, 1, 7\,\rangle$, this will result in a $b$ array $\langle\,1, 3, 4, 7\,\rangle$, which has all the values without duplicates, but the original place order of the elements isn't preserved. There are at least two possibilities for the result, depending on whether you want to eliminate all the duplicate values after the first occurrence, (giving you $\langle\,7, 3, 4, 1\,\rangle$) or if you want to eliminate all the duplicate values before the last occurrence, giving you $\langle\,4, 3, 1, 7\,\rangle$.

For the first option, a fairly simple modification is to do a preprocessing step on the $a$ array, changing it to an array of pairs, $(value, index)$, where $index$ is the position of the element with that value. In the example above, this will give you a new array
$$
\langle\,(7, 0), (3, 1), (7, 2), (4, 3), (1, 4), (3, 5), (1, 6), (7, 7)\,\rangle
$$
Now, as we did originally, sort this array by the first element of the pairs, giving
$$
\langle\,(1, 4), (1, 6), (3, 1), (3, 5), (4, 3), (7, 0), (7, 2), (7, 7)\,\rangle
$$
(here we need to use a stable sort, like mergesort, to maintain the original place order). Eliminating duplicates, as above, we will have
$$
\langle\,(1, 4), (3, 1), (4, 3), (7, 0)\,\rangle
$$
and if we sort the result by the second index, we'll have
$$
\langle\,(7, 0), (3, 1), (4, 3), (1, 4)\,\rangle
$$
and looking at the first element, we'll have $\langle\,7, 3, 4, 1\,\rangle$, which is what we wanted.

This algorithm will take $O(n)$ steps to preprocess the array, $O(n\log n)$ steps to sort the result, $O(n)$ steps to eliminate the duplicate values, and $O(n\log n)$ steps to do the final sort, giving us an algorithnm that runs in time $O(n+n\log n+n+n\log n)=O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Since arrays are usually static, an additional step with known size of `b` may be necessary.

Comment: Yes, time is not the issue, just completeness. My point was that you can't allocate `b` before your scan of sorted `a`, so your code would have to have another allocation + copy phase after the scan. That is, if we want a result array with no empty entries.

Comment: @Raphael  "if" indeed. Frankly, as long as I kept track of the length of $b$ as I was scanning $a$, I'd be happy with some junk entries in the tail of $b$. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution (pseudocode):

```
Duplicate(A: array):
  Array B = Merge-sort(A)
  Array Vect // New Vector
  int p=2
  Vect[1] = B[1]
  for i=2 to B.lenght{
    if (B[i]<>B[i-1]) then
        Vect[p] = B[i]
        p = p+1
   }
 return Vect
```

is correct?

Comment: We don't do answer checking, and in particular not checking for code in real programming languages. If you translate Rick's answer into any language, you'll get something correct.

Comment: ok but there are more polite ways to say these things. I am here to learn.

Comment: You misspelled `length`.

Comment: Heh. Looks like your introduction to this site hasn't been particularly pleasant. Don't let it discourage you. Remember, in a text-only medium like this, you don't get the nuances you would in face to face communications, so some comments might strike you as ruder than the poster intended. Cultivate a thicker skin and let perceived rudeness slide off. By the way, thanks for the acceptance and welcome to the site.

Comment: Calm, everything is alright! Excuse me for my response sour, but I'm studying for an exam, and the tension is so great. :)